# (CENTOS 7 Apache/Nginx/Mysql) Откуда столько соединений?

Tags: nginx, centos, unix

Всем привет.
с 8 утра наблюдаем нездоровую картину.
Есть сервер, выделенный, с 8 утра у него адский трафик на порту, занят весь. Полная загрузка процов. Сайт в 502 ушел ( весь сервак под 1 сайт )

Ребут сервисов, как и сервера не помогает.
Нагрузку сбросить не можем.

По нетстату видно вот что

```
$ netstat -n -p | awk '{print $6}'|awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n10
 - 48562 ESTABLISHED
 - 9512 TIME_WAIT
 - 8757 SYN_SENT
 - 532 SYN_RECV
 - 314 CONNECTED
 - 197 FIN_WAIT1
 - 58 FIN_WAIT2
 - 8 LAST_ACK
 - 3 CLOSING
 - 2 CLOSE_WAIT
```

```
$ netstat -n -p | awk '{print $5}'|awk -F: '{print $1}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n10
28189 127.0.0.1
```

```
$ sudo netstat -nput | awk '{print $4}'|awk -F: '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n10
 - 52914 443
 - 495 8888
 - 76 11211
 - 59 80
 - 10
 - 8 21
 - 3 22
 - 2 60998
 - 2 60980
 - 2 60968
```

Откуда такое и в чем может быть причина ?

Comment: вас DDoS-ят, скорее всего :D. Выберите самые нажористые сети и заблочьте их по ойпи

Comment: Это первая мысль которая пришла... Но так долго, уже порядка 4 часов...да и волже f2b стоит.

Comment: ddos-ить могут долго,  а fail2ban реагирует на события логов, а не на факт соединения. посмотрите на распределение айпишников по подсетям. может быть поймете, ddos это или какая-то ошибка чьих-то сетевых настроек, и на вас левый траф льется

Comment: Вообщем, DDOS. 4 млн ботов ....

Comment: ну, если вы не госструктура и вас собираются еще ддосить, прячьтесь за cloudflare

Comment: Баньте по ASN, так полезней :)

Comment: в связи с https://twitter.com/VessOnSecurity/status/1074598179662905344 было бы интересно, если бы вы куда-нибудь скинули топчик атакующих сетей /ip